# override a configuration file using volumes on docker

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose

i'm trying to override the context.xml file on a docker container using volume mapping feature on docker-compose file

```
volumes:
  - /tmp/project/context.xml /opt/apache-tomcat/webapps/project/METAINF/context.xml
```

the problem is that METAINF directory contains other files and when mounting the volumes docker deletes the files keeping only the context.xml file
is there a way to map only the context.xml file without deleting the other files ?
PS: docker-compose version is 2.1

Comment: You can use a dockerfile for that. Take the image you want, and copy the file in the location.

`COPY f/tmp/project/context.xml /path/to/file.txt`

Comment: i don't want to modify the dockerfile nor create another image for this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, without modifying the dockerfile. But I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to mount a single file without replacing the directory. What you are trying should Just Work. You haven't provided enough information for us to reproduce your specific problem, but here's an example:

I don't have a tomcat application handy, so let's assume I want to replace the file `/etc/issue` with a local file.

I would structure my `docker-compose.yaml` like this:

```
services:
  web:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd
    volumes:
      - ./issue:/etc/issue
```

Assuming that my local `issue` file contains:

```
This is a test
```

Then after brining up this environment...

```
docker compose up -d
```

...the `/etc` directory still contains all the expected files:

```
$ docker compose exec web ls /etc
alpine-release   group-           modprobe.d       opt              protocols        shells
apk              hostname         modules          os-release       resolv.conf      ssl
busybox-paths.d  hosts            modules-load.d   passwd           secfixes.d       ssl1.1
conf.d           init.d           motd             passwd-          securetty        sysctl.conf
crontabs         inittab          mtab             periodic         services         sysctl.d
fstab            issue            network          profile          shadow           udhcpd.conf
group            logrotate.d      nsswitch.conf    profile.d        shadow-
```

But `/etc/issue` has my custom content:

```
$ docker compose exec web cat /etc/issue
This is a test
```

Comment: i can't see this isn't the case for me . i provided the code to reproduce the isseue

Comment: @aymen0406 have the same issues with you, the xml yml become a directory ...
have you spotted out the problem ?

Comment: Generally ,when a file mount shows up as a directory in your container that means that there is a problem with your host path. If you're running under MacOS or Windows things can be a little trickier because Docker is actually running inside a Linux VM. There are facilities for controlling what host directories are available to Docker, but I haven't worked with anything other than Linux for years so I can't offer a suggestion. You may want to open a new question with the specific details of your situation.